# inspect native code

Tags: javascript

Is there any way by which I can explore native code in Javascript?  I want to see what Function() class has in it.

Comment: Ehh? There's a specification, if you'd like that? JavaScript is determined by it, and as so, for a non-browser-specific way to look at it, that's the way you want to go.

Comment: not exactly byte code...but the native classes and functions. For example if you write alert(Function) then you see Function(){[native code]}. So I want to explore this native code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could have a look at the [source code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Download_Mozilla_Source_Code) of an open source browser such as Firefox.

Comment: any other way to do it in runtime?

Comment: @marcioAlmada: At runtime, no.  The code for `Function` (and most other built-ins) isn't Javascript; it's native code.  In order to do it at runtime, the script engine would have to have an embedded native-code disassembler or something.  Which none that i know of do.

Answer (score 2):

I've always wanted to do this myself. On a side note, here's how to view assembly language code generated by the V8 JS engine for Chromium (I haven't tried it yet): [How can I see the machine code generated by v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277423/how-can-i-see-the-machine-code-generated-by-v8)