# How can I read ‘native code’ JavaScript functions?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to see the declaration of JavaScript native code? Whenever I try to look at a native function in Chrome or Firefox, it says "`native code`":

```
> String.fromCharCode
function fromCharCode() { [native code] }
```

What does this mean, and is there any tool which can help me to read actual code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [inspect native code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2872861/inspect-native-code)

Comment: See also [How to get native javascript functions source code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22371251/1048572)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The reason Chrome or Firefox says that the code is native is that it really is native - the WebKit and Firefox developers have coded up that functionality in C or C++, not JavaScript.  However, if you want to see the actual code, you can look at the source repositories for [Chromium](http://src.chromium.org/viewvc) and [Firefox](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/).

Comment: I agree but I thought maybe some extension is there which does that for me. I can look into documentation but I was looking for a shortcut.

Comment: Is there a way to look into native webkit code for Safari? I'm debugging an issue with webkitAudioContext (HTML5 WebAudio API). Dealing with ScriptProcessorNode, works fine in Chrome & Firefox and behaves weirdly in Safari. Since Safari code isn't open, is there a way to debug using something like `ptrace`?

Comment: how can search what i want in this doc?!

Answer (score 34):

Not within the JavaScript environment, but you can view the source for the open-source implementations.

Google V8: http://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse

Mozilla SpiderMonkey: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey

Comment: That's very useful but I was looking within a console or something. A shortcut. Going to documentation and search for it was annoying. Anyways thank you for replying.

Answer (score -1):

Firefox now supports the inspection of "[native code]" objects via standard dev tools.

To see it in action:

1. update Firefox (definitely works w/ v68+, may work with older versions as well)
2. open dev tools
3. go to the Console
4. type the name of a native object, e.g., "Document"
5. hit return
6. go nuts on all those little dropdown arrows

[FireFox - inspect "native code" - Document object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOvH6.png)

Chrome still returns *ƒ Document() { [native code] }*, unfortunately.

[Chrome - DON'T inspect "native code" - disappointment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkU82.png)

Comment: This doesn't show the source code of the function, it just shows the object properties of the function object like `console.dir(Document)` does.

Comment: I agree with Bergi. I used FF 80, ran `Number.prototype.constructor.toString()` and got `"function Number() { [native code] }"` as output.