# What does " [native code] " mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, native-code

I tried to investigate the jQuery code, so I used this:

```
document.write($.constructor);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WZGWp/)

I got this result:

```
function Function() { [native code] }
```

What does `[native code]` mean? Why can't I see the real code?

<sub>Tested with `Google-Chrome`</sub>

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103336/read-javascript-native-code?

Comment: Possibly `constructor` method is inherited from JS object, which is part of basic browser functionality.

Comment: @gdoron It doesn't answer the question directly, but jQuery is open source, so you can see for yourself what is in there.

Comment: Because that code is part of the V8 engine, which is implemented in C++ and therefore compiled code.

Comment: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/toString) source, for completeness

Answer (score 77, accepted):

When you define functions in an interpreted language (as opposed to a compiled language). You have access to the file / string / text that defines the function.

In JavaScript for example you can read the definition body text of a function you have defined:

```js
function custom( param ){
  console.log( param );
}

console.log( custom.toString() ); // <- Will display the full code (in text) of the function.
```

If you try to do the same for a function that is *included* by construction* in JavaScript it is not implemented as text but as binary.

```js
console.log( setInterval.toString() );

// Will display: function setInterval() { [native code] }
```

There is no reason to show the binary code that implements that function because it is not readable and it might not even be available.

jQuery extends default JavaScript behaviour. It's one of the reasons it was so highly appreciated and praised as opposed to Prototype.js for example. Prototype was *altering* the natural behaviour of JavaScript creating possible inconsistencies when using Prototype alongside some other piece of code that relied on normal functionality.

### tl;dr:

jQuery extends JavaScript, there is functionality implemented using native code (which performance wise is a good thing).

---

**included by construction*: Elaborating a bit on this part. JavaScript itself can be written/implemented in any language (C++, Java, etc.). In Chrome, the JavaScript engine (V8) is written in C++. Firefox's JavaScript engine (SpiderMonkey) is also written in C++.

The functions that are defined by the language specification (ECMAScript) and should be included in the actual implementation, are written in another language (e.g. C++ in these 2 cases) and become available in JavaScript as built-in/**native** functions.

These functions are actually compiled (binary) C++ code and thus cannot be displayed within JavaScript itself, e.g. using the `[].map.toString()` syntax.

Comment: This answer explained the mystery of `[native code]` very well. Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by "included by construction" ?

Comment: @doubleOrt I think he's refering to the engine

Comment: @Mihai Stancu Could you explain the "included by construction" part?

Answer (score 28):

`$`, `jQuery` is just a function. Without invoking it, it's just an ordinary function. A function's constructor is `Function`, hence `$.constructor` shows `[native code]`.

Comment: Just to be sure, it has nothing to do with jQuery at all right, the other answer confused me.

Comment: @gdoron jQuery is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: @RobW I have this code jQuery.colorbox.close()  and how to convert in native javascript

Answer (score 3):

bind does this to functions:

> ```
> var f = function() { /* source code */ };
> console.log(f.toString());
> ```

```
function () { /* source code */ }
```

> ```
> var a = {};
> f = f.bind(a);
> console.log(f.toString());
> ```

```
function () { [native code] }
```

> ```
> f = new Function('/* source code */');
> console.log(f.toString());
> ```

```
function anonymous() { /* source code */ }
```

> ```
> f = f.bind(a);
> console.log(f.toString());
> ```

```
function () { [native code] }
```

either bind returns a reference to some kind of a wrapper code, or toString considers the bound copy native since it is not created by the user directly

However, just logging function directly, w/o using toString(), prints (in Chrome) the source code of the original unbound function:

> ```
> f = f.bind(a);
> console.log(f)
> ```

```
ƒ () { /* source code */ }
```

in FF this doesn't work though - FF prints the function object, w/o the source code