# Debugging JavaScript in Visual Studio, what does [native code] mean

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm debugging some JavaScript in Visual Studio 2013 and when inspecting some variables I'm seeing [native code] for some variables.  For instance:

```
Variable r =>
function slice() {
    [native code]
}
    Object, (Function)
```

Does that mean that it's not JavaScript code, like C# or something?  The app I'm debugging is an ASP.NET website.

Comment: Yes. It means it's a [*built–in*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.7) function.

Comment: Oh, so it's just the built-in slice function?  Seems kind of strange that they assigned that to a variable, but oh well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does " \[native code\] " mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234664/what-does-native-code-mean)

Comment: @Eric—yes. You should get the same result for all built–in objects (noting that functions are objects).

Comment: the built in slice function is not assigned to a variable, that would be strange. also note that any bound functions will give the same "source code", even if they are normally user-land functions.

Comment: Here's a simplified example of what's going on in the minified JavaScript I'm trying to debug: `<script> 

function myFunc() {
    var r = [].slice;
    var u = r.call(arguments);
}
debugger;
myFunc(1,2,3,4,5);</script>`So basically they're using the local slice variable as a way to store the function arguments to a local array.