# Javascript object lost constructor when the prototype was changed

Tags: javascript, prototype

In below code

```
var A = function() {};
var a = new A();
var b = new A();

A.prototype = {};

var c = new A();
console.log(a.constructor === b.constructor);
console.log(a.constructor === c.constructor);
```

output is `true` and `false`.

I am interested in the false output. `a` and `c` were created using **same** constructor function which is `A` - why is their constructor property different? It seems I miss something.

PS. If I remove the line where I am changing prototype of A output is: `true true`.

Comment: I tried printing `a.constructor` and `c.constructor`. This may be relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234664/what-does-native-code-mean

Comment: apology, this gives a good explanation http://javascript.info/tutorial/constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you construct an object, the constructor's `prototype` property is *copied* to the new object's `__proto__`, so while `a` and `b` retain the old prototype (which also contains the `.constructor` property), `c` uses the new blank prototype (which doesn't have `constructor` as own property). Here's a diagram:

After `a = new A; b = new A`:

[image]

After `A.prototype = {}; c = new A()`

[image]

As you can see, direct assignment to a prototype breaks the JS object system and may lead to surprising results (which your very question demonstrates). That's why it's generally frowned upon.

Comment: I would love to know what software you used to create that diagram!

Comment: Why changing prototype of function affects the constructor property of object?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava: objects don't have an intrinsic `constructor` property, it belongs to a prototype.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you use `A.prototype={}` it is changed the behavior of `A` object.

When you use `A.prototype={}`, A object lost it’s `constructor`.

> Why it is this behavior ?

**The `constructor` property is assigned to `prototype` function.**

And in your case ,`A.prototype` is replaced with a new Object `{}`, which doesn't have `constructor` property as own property (but its prototype has and is equal to `Object`).

Lets see the following example:

```
function A() { } // (1)
A.prototype = {}  // (2)
```

Before (2)

```
Object.prototype
{
    constructor:Object
}

A.prototype
//was autocreated with A
{
    constructor:A
}
```

After (2)

```
Object.prototype
{
    constructor:Object
}

A.prototype
//reassigned with {}
{
   //no constructor
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using function as an object constructor, its `prototype.constructor` is automatically created with function's property.  So initially after setting up the A function you will have a constructor in A's prototype:

```
A.prototype.constructor
```

So when you assign A.prototype ={}, you lost that original constructor in `A.prototype`.

You may fix it with adding this after `A.prototype ={}` line

```
A.prototype.constructor = A;
```

Both console should log true