# What is the HTMLDocument function?

Tags: javascript, html, htmldoc

I have noticed that if you write a program like this:

```js
console.log(document);
```

It shows `[object HTMLDocument]`.
Then, if you do this:

```js
console.log(HTMLDocument);
```

it shows this:

```js
function HTMLDocument() {
   [native code]
}
```

So, I am wondering what the `HTMLDocument` function is, and what its code is.
Thanks!

Comment: It's the constructor function for `HTMLDocument` objects.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument

Comment: Yes, but what code does ```[native code]``` refer to?

Comment: Code of the JS Engine. `console.log(Array.from)`

Comment: `[native code]` refers to the native code of the browser: [What does “ \[native code\] ” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11234664/215552) See also [Read JavaScript native code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9103336/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the constructor of the HTMLDocument object.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLDocument):

> The HTMLDocument interface, which may be accessed through the
>   Window.HTMLDocument property, extends the Window.HTMLDocument property
>   to include methods and properties that are specific to HTML documents.

Native code is a core functionality offered by the browser rather than a code written in Javascript.