# What is the Comment (native) function?

Tags: javascript

In console, in both Firefox and Chrome, typing `Comment` outputs

```
ƒ Comment() { [native code] }
```

What is it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234664/what-does-native-code-mean

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103336/how-can-i-read-native-code-javascript-functions

Comment: @Quentin I don't think he's asking what 'native code' means, he wants to know what this function does.

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interface that creates an [HTML comment object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Comment) when called with `new`:

```js
const c = new Comment();

console.log(c);
```