# window functions callback explanation

Tags: javascript, variables, callback

Hello guys runned into this issue

can someone explains me how this works?

```
function anyOther(){
    return "otherFunction";
}

function getLocation() {
    return window.location.toString();
}

function myFunc(data, func) {
    console.log(data, func());
}

myFunc("From", getLocation);
myFunc("From", anyOther);
myFunc("From", window.location.toString);
```

why passing window.location.toString() inline does not work and passing it after we wrap it in a function works

https://jsfiddle.net/w9jhdzm7/

Comment: what is `console.log(data,func())` there is no `func` function in your code., see your browser's console.

Comment: @yash func is give as argument to myFunc

Comment: Try `myFunc("From", window.location.toString.bind(window.location));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the third myfunc call you are passing a function of the window object.

```
function anyOther(){
    return "otherFunction";
}

function getLocation() {
    return window.location.toString();
}

function myFunc(data, func) {
    console.log(data, func());
}

myFunc("From", getLocation);
myFunc("From", anyOther);
```

This is not working because this function will only work in the context of the window object. Now you are calling it not in the context of the window object.

> ```
> myFunc("From", window.location.toString);
> ```

This is because you are passing a reference of the function to the myFunc function which then tries to call this function. Because this is not in the context of the window object this will fail.

### When not to pass functions as reference:

When the functions are native implementations of the browser you can't pass the functions as arguments in another function. You can see if it is a implementation of the browser if you can see [native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9103336/read-javascript-native-code) like this:

[image]

`window.Object.assign` is a function which is implemented by the browsers and thus we cannot pass this as function argument and expect it to work.

Comment: nice explanation so this only has to do with the fact that im calling a function of window there is any other case which i should take care of?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do this :

```
myFunc("From", window.location.toString);
```

Inside `myFunc`, the function is called on the global object, not on `window.location`