# Why is my node.js "shell script" running significantly faster the second time called and beyond?

Tags: node.js, caching, bytecode

I have a large JS file that's generated by a build process. I've noticed that after I make a change it takes much longer to run the first time, and then subsequent executions are quicker:

```
$ node --version
v12.5.0

$ time node build/jsx/my_script.js 
real    0m4.188s
user    0m0.144s
sys     0m0.417s

$ time node build/jsx/my_script.js 
real    0m0.602s
user    0m0.141s
sys     0m0.404s

$ time node build/jsx/my_script.js 
real    0m0.569s
user    0m0.145s
sys     0m0.369s
```

Over 4 seconds for the first run, but then around half a second for subsequent runs. Even if I leave the terminal and do other work for a while, re-running my script stays fast, until its source gets rebuilt. So I don't think it's just a generic operating system cache.

I know that other scripting languages can cache an internal representation of the script to speed up subsequent runs, e.g. [Python has its `*.pyc` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998215/if-python-is-interpreted-what-are-pyc-files). However, I was not aware that node.js did anything like this. It certainly doesn't leave any obvious cache files around that I've noticed.

Most of the answers on [Does nodejs/V8 store compiled machine code anywhere on disk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673515/does-nodejs-v8-store-compiled-machine-code-anywhere-on-disk) are stale, and the currently accepted one only reveals the `--print-bytecode` option without answer where or if node.js stores the bytecode between runs. It certainly looks like it's possible for node.js to be using some sort of bytecode cache (e.g. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11842) but it's unclear if it actually **does**.

How is node.js able to run my script so much faster after one initial slower execution? Is there a way to "warm up" the mechanism without actually running the script? Is there a way to "bypass" the mechanism for testing worst-case performance?

Comment: Under `node --v8-options`, I did find one called `--compilation-cache` which defaults to true. So I suspect that's part of the answer, but still haven't found much additional detail re. where its stored and how it is validated against an old vs. rebuilt script.