# Adding in Javascript (NodeJS)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to maximize my [FLOPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLOPS) in NodeJS, so I want to add using bitwise operations.

So:

```
var a = 6, b = 12;
a + b
```

Instead:

```
var add = function (a, b) {
    var carry, result, shiftedcarry;

    carry = a & b,
    result = a ^ b;

    while (carry !== 0) {
        shiftedcarry = carry << 1;
        carry = result & shiftedcarry;
        result ^= shiftedcarry;
    }

    return result;
}

add(a, b);
```

However, I found SO answers that said bitwise operations are slower in Javascript due to casting. Is there anyway to bypass this problem (like with a V8 extension or something)?

The reason I'm so focused on increasing my FLOPS is because I'm thinking of running a NodeJS experiment on a supercomputer.

Comment: If you're worried about this, you probably shouldn't be writing this in JavaScript.  V8 is fast, but very far from optimal.

Comment: That's what V8's JIT is for. In most cases you don't need to 'optimize' but rather you need to avoid deoptimization. Here's a link that can get you started: https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers

Comment: I believe this is the case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 2):

V8 is a pretty good JIT.  After enough iterations it will optimize the simple a + b better than you can.

I made a jspref test to demonstrate: http://jsperf.com/add-optimization

If you want to really dive in you can poke at V8's output [How can I see the machine code generated by v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277423/how-can-i-see-the-machine-code-generated-by-v8)