# How can I transfer JS to native machine code (using v8)

Tags: javascript, code-generation, v8

I've tried the suggest in the url:
[How can I see the machine code generated by v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277423/how-can-i-see-the-machine-code-generated-by-v8)

Here is what I did:

```
git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools

sudo apt-get install libv8-dev
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
sudo apt-get install g++-multilib

export PATH="$PATH":`pwd`/depot_tools

fetch v8

gclient sync

make ia32.release objectprint=on disassembler=on

v8/out/ia32.release/d8 --print-all-code hello.js > output.txt
```

(The script is just:print("hello"))

Below are the output:

```
kind = STUB
major_key = JSEntryStub
compiler = unknown
Instructions (size = 131)
0x35d06040     0  55             push ebp
0x35d06041     1  89e5           mov ebp,esp
0x35d06043     3  6a02           push 0x2
......
0x35d060c2    82  c3             ret
Handler Table (size = 12)

RelocInfo (size = 23)
0x35d06047  external reference (Isolate::context_address)  (0xa9533dc)
0x35d06050  external reference (Isolate::c_entry_fp_address)  (0xa953410)
......
kind = STUB
major_key = JSEntryStub
compiler = unknown
Instructions (size = 131)
0x35d06120     0  55             push ebb
......
```

Indeed,I have a batch of code,but it doesn't vary from the input script.
By the way,the output is certainly too much(about 13M text) for a simple script.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you're trying to do something that does not make sense. See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Much of the code you gonna see produced by the jit is likely from the V8 runtime libraries, which (1) is a lot, and (2) the same for different scripts. Try searching the output for some unique identifiers from your code.

Answer (score 2):

With current V8 versions (5.9 or later), you probably want the `--print-opt-code` flag: initially, V8 generates byte code for its interpreter (which you can inspect with `--print-bytecode`); once a function is "hot" (i.e. a lot of time is spent executing it), it is sent to the optimizing compiler to generate machine code for it.

Note that you cannot use V8 as a general purpose JavaScript-to-machine-code compiler. The flags mentioned above are intended for debugging; there is no (supported or easy) way to produce working binaries from their output.