# V8 will not print out disassembly

Tags: javascript, v8

I compiled v8 with the disassembler option:

```
tools/dev/v8gen.py x64.debug -- v8_enable_disassembler=true  v8_enable_object_print=true
ninja -C out.gn/x64.debug
```

However, when I attempt to print out the disassembly, d8 does not output anything (no error messages either):

```
./d8 --print-code test.js
```

test.js contains the following:

```
function add(a, b){
  return a + b;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I see the machine code generated by v8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277423/how-can-i-see-the-machine-code-generated-by-v8)

Answer (score 2):

V8 compiles functions lazily (i.e. when they are first called), so when your file only contains `function add(...) {...}`, that is one reason why you're not seeing any output. Try adding a call, e.g. `add(1, 1)`.

Also, recent versions of V8 use a bytecode interpreter instead of generating machine code right away. You can print the bytecode using `--print-bytecode`.

Machine code is only generated by the optimizing compiler once a function is "hot" (for a small function like `add` in your test, that means calling it a few thousand times); `--print-opt-code` prints the optimized machine code.

(Side note: In Debug builds of V8, disassembler support is always enabled, so you don't need any custom flags.)